# Transformation of Pandas Dataframe from long to wide format

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform below dataframe in wide format

| Date | category | cat-count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1-2022 | Login | 5 |
| 1-1-2022 | Accounts | 10 |
| 2-1-2022 | Login | 9 |
| 3-1-2022 | Accounts | 10 |
| 3-1-2022 | Login | 15 |

Desired Output

| Date | Login | Accounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1-2022 | 5 | 10 |
| 2-1-2022 | 9 | 0 |
| 3-1-2022 | 10 | 15 |

How can i get this Output by Pandas python or any python method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1-1-2022', '1-1-2022', '2-1-2022', '3-1-2022', '3-1-2022'],
                   'cat': ['Login', 'Accounts', 'Login', 'Accounts', 'Login'],
                   'cat-cnt': [5, 10, 9, 10, 15]})

df_new = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['date'], columns=['cat'], fill_value=0.0)
```

Result:

```
df_new =

          cat-cnt      
cat      Accounts Login
date                   
1-1-2022       10     5
2-1-2022        0     9
3-1-2022       10    15


df_new['cat-cnt']['Accounts'] =

date
1-1-2022    10
2-1-2022     0
3-1-2022    10
Name: Accounts, dtype: int64
```